# How to symlink a jar file in a Maven project for consumption by another local project

Tags: java, maven, jar

Assume I have 2 projects locally. One is a server (end application) and another is a library. I want to symlink the library (a jar file) to the application. I believe all I need to do is symlink the jar file to the maven / m2 directory.

For example here is the hibernate jar in `~/.m2` dir

[image]

the hibernate folder is at:

```
~/.m2/repository/org/hibernate
```

I see some jar files in there, but also pom.xml files, so how do I include those?

Perhaps there is a maven command line tool?

```
mvn symlink
```

that would simply create symlinks in the global space to the local project?

Comment: Can't you just do `mvn install`?

Comment: @tkausl yes but will `mvn install` keep it up to date if I update the library as I work on the server? I am looking to develop the two projects in tandem. See the updates to the question.

Comment: Depends on the IDE you're using, but a symlink won't help either. You'd have to package anyway so might aswell just install.

Comment: Yeah but the install will copy files, the symlink would be slightly faster?

Comment: How about a [multi module project](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html)?

Comment: @tkausl multi-module looks kinda complicated for my use case now..`mvn install` will prob work for now, but my only concern is when my server app will pick up changes to the library jar - I wonder if I have to bump the version or something, that would suck.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you have two Maven projects (`server` and `library`) and `server` depends on `library`. You want develop both applications simultaneously.

Option one would be a multi-module project. Then you build and deploy both applications at the same time and have no problem with stale dependencies.

Option two would be to have two different Maven projects. During development, I would stick with SNAPSHOT versions. So you define a dependency from `server` to `library` with a version like `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`. When you do a `mvn install` on the `library`, the `server` will pick up the changes immediately (if you are on the same computer) or after a defined interval (when you work on different computers with a Nexus/Artifactory in between).

If you work with Eclipse, option two allows you to do "Workspace Resolution", so that the `server` project will pick up the changes in the `library` project without the necessity of explicitly calling Maven.

Comment: yeah two different Maven projects should be totally sufficient, the library is for other people, not just for my server project.